# How to attach a class level filter with dependency injection?

Tags: nestjs

I am trying to catch failures within a specific controller with filters. My filter requires access to another service (to save in db) and I am not sure how to have a class level filter with dependency injection (DI so that the filter has access to the service).

I've currently passing the service from the controller where I use the decorator `UseFilters` but realized that decorators don't share the same scope.

```
@UseFilters(new UnprocessableEntityExceptionFilter(myService))
```

```
@Catch(UnprocessableEntityException)
export class UnprocessableEntityExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  constructor(private readonly requestsService: RequestsService) { }

  async catch(exception: UnprocessableEntityException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse();
    const request = ctx.getRequest();

    const status = exception.getStatus();
    const body = exception.message;

    response.status(status).json(body);
    await this.requestsService.create(request, response, body);
  }
}
```

And I want to use this filter at the class level like this...

```
@UseFilters(new UnprocessableEntityExceptionFilter())
export class EventsController {
  constructor() { }

  @Get()
  async get() {
   ...
  }
```

But I clearly cannot create a new instance of `UnprocessableEntityExceptionFilter` because it requires dependency injection.

I understand the documentation tells us to use this method when filters have dependency injection, but I don't want this filter to be global.

> ```
> @Module({
>   providers: [
>     {
>       provide: APP_FILTER,
>       useClass: HttpExceptionFilter,
>     },
>   ],
> })
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this

```
@UseFilters(UnprocessableEntityExceptionFilter)
export class EventsController {}
```